# How do I get the json object in the request body in webflux?

Tags: json, spring-webflux

I am trying to parse json data from request body to JsonOject.

[Spring Reactive get body JSONObject using ServerRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870517/spring-reactive-get-body-jsonobject-using-serverrequest/52886199?noredirect=1#comment110430946_52886199)

```
// it didn't work.
JSONObject bodyData = serverRequest.bodyToMono(JSONObject.class).toProcessor().peek();
```

I tried it as referenced in the link above, but it didn't work.
I want to know why this is.

For the test, two router beans were created as shown below.

```
  // router
  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routeJsonBodyPOST2(JsonObjectHandler jsonObjectHandler) {
    return route(RequestPredicates.POST("/json/post2")
        .and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)).and(contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)), jsonObjectHandler::getStringByJsonObject);
  }

  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routeJsonBodyPOST3(JsonObjectHandler jsonObjectHandler) {
    return route(RequestPredicates.POST("/json/post3")
        .and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)).and(contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)), jsonObjectHandler::getJsonObject);
  }
```

```
  // handler
  // I checked the json data in onNext. I understood this.
  public Mono<ServerResponse> getStringByJsonObject(ServerRequest request) {

    Mono<String> response = request.bodyToMono(JSONObject.class).log()
        .map(jsonObject -> {
          String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
          System.out.println(name);
          return name;
        });

    return ServerResponse.ok()
        .body(response, String.class);
  }
```

[image]

```
  // Only onComplete is called and exits. I don't understand this.
  public Mono<ServerResponse> getJsonObject(ServerRequest request) {

    Mono<JSONObject> response = request.bodyToMono(JSONObject.class).log();
    response.onErrorResume(error -> {
      System.out.println(error);
      return Mono.error(error);
    }).subscribe(
        jsonObject -> System.out.println("test : " + jsonObject),
        error -> System.out.println(error.getMessage()),
        () -> System.out.println("complete")
    );

    //    Mono<JSONObject> jsonObjectMono = request.bodyToMono(JSONObject.class);
    //    jsonObjectMono.subscribe(System.out::println);

    //    JSONObject peek = jsonObjectMono.toProcessor().peek();
    //    System.out.println(peek);
    
    // just for test.
    return ServerResponse.ok().build();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you expect in `getJsonObject` method?

Comment: @diziaq I want to subscribe to json data requested by request and print it out or send it as a response.